# SSRS Generate uniqueid per row

Tags: reporting-services

Hi so I am using an fx for my query. When I run the report I want the first column to be an ID column with a unique id per row or just number the rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. Is there and expression or something built in SSRS to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I added a column called id  and in the field bx I right clicked and in expression chose miscilanneous and rownumber......